# Passing model to controller from view in JTable MVC using jQuery

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery-jtable

I am trying to pass entire model from View to Controller using jTable. 
Here is the code for view

I am having a filter criteria based on which the table will be loaded.
Say DropdownList of ModelId and ModelName, on selection,followed by click of a button, the function below executes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetModels() {

        var model = {
        ModelId:$("#ModelId").val(),
        ModelName:$("#ModelName").val(),
        ModelAge:$("#ModelAge").val()
     };


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Table of Models',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/Controller/ActionName'

            },

            fields: {
                ModelName: {
                   title: 'ModelName',
                    width: '30%',
                    list: false
                },

                ModelId: {
                    title: 'ModelId',
                    width: '30%',
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                }

                ModelAge: {
                    title: 'ModelAge',
                    width: '30%',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                }
            }
        });
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load', { ModelName: model });


    });
    }
```

Here is the code for the controller.

```
public JsonResult GetAppropriateModel( ModelName ModelName)
    {
        try
        {
           FillAppropriateModel(ModelName);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "Error", Message=e.Message });
        }

    }
```

I am kind of new in AJAX and I am facing an issue where in the returned model is null, However if I cause normal submit-button postaction, then the model is retained.. I googled and got examples where they pass discrete elements and not entire model.
--Edit --
This is the link I referred.
http://www.jtable.org/Demo/Filtering


Kindly help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the MVC handler doesn't decode model objects properly when jTable sends them in.  I've found that setting the contentType in your jTable ajaxSettings fixes this.  In your jTable definitions, add this:

```
ajaxSettings: {
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
```

Then you have to stringify your parameter when you send it in:

```
$('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load', JSON.stringify({ ModelName: model }));
```